# How to test a function that uses db and returns boolean depending on the parameters

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest

I made a function to check if a specific user has permissions to make some action on a resource.
If the user has super permissions `has_all_actions, has_all_resources` it can make any action on any resource.
I don't know if i implemented the function well, but with some manual tests i made it's working.

```
def check_if_user_has_permissions(user= None, resource = None, action = None):

    tmp = {}
    tmp["user"] = user
    tmp["resource"] = resource
    tmp["action"] = action
    data = []
    has_permission = db.session.query(RoleMember.user_uid, Permission.resource, Permission.action). \
        filter_by(user_uid=user). \
        join(Permission, Permission.role == RoleMember.role).all()
    if resource and action is not None:
        if has_permission == "":
            return False
        else:
            for info in has_permission:
                for item in info:
                    data.append(item)
            has_all_actions = "*"
            has_all_resources = "machines/*"
            if tmp["user"] in data and data[1] == has_all_resources and data[2] == has_all_actions:
                return True
            else:
                if tmp["user"] in data and tmp["resource"] in data and tmp["action"] in data:
                    return True
                else:
                    return False
    else:
        return False
```

This functions returns true of false depending if the user has permissions or not and returns always true if the user has super permissions: `has_all_actions, has_all_resources`.

My database is SqlAlchemy but at the moment I'am using this `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI: "sqlite://"` so i don't have real data stored in the db.

Now i want to test this function with `@pytest.mark.parametrize`, so I pass different parameters to the actual function and assert that is false or true depending on the data that is on the database.

So i think i also need to mock the database and add some data there so i can do this test? or is there a way without mocking the db?

Any examples i can follow? I'am lost in this.

Forgot to show my models:

```
class Role(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "roles"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(250), unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(1000))
    permissions = db.relationship("Permission", lazy=True)
    members = db.relationship("RoleMember", lazy=True)


class Permission(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "permissions"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    resource = db.Column(db.String(250))
    action = db.Column(db.String(250))
    role = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("roles.id"))


class RoleMember(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "role_members"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_uid = db.Column(db.String(250))
    role = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("roles.id"))
```

Answer (score 0):

So i found the answer, the problem was that my `has_permission` was returning a type `[(" ")]` and i was making the mock returning a type [" "].

So the solution was:

```
@patch("dev_maintenance.roles.db")
def test_check_if_user_has_permissions(db):

    tmp = {}
    tmp["user"] = "bender"
    tmp["resource"] = "machine/1"
    tmp["action"] = "delete"



    ##The mock
    db.session.query.return_value.filter_by.return_value.join.return_value.all.return_value = [(tmp["user"], tmp["resource"], tmp["action"])]
    ## check if the function is returning True

    assert check_if_user_has_permissions("bender","machine/1", "delete") == True
```